# Devart Oracle Cross Apply Exception

Tags: linq, oracle, entity-framework, devart, cross-apply

I´m running a problem where in one machine the code works and another don´t. Apparently we´re using the same Devart dotConnect for Oracle version (6.80.325.0). The problem is when we have a subquery in the LINQ and we get Cross Apply Not Supported for Oracle.

```
public IQueryable<GE_MENUAPLICACAO> RetornaMenusNegadosParaUsuario2(int seqUsuario, int nroEmpresa)
    {
        return from usuarioPerm in entidadesConsinco.GE_USUARIOPERMISSAO
               from menu in usuarioPerm.GE_ITENSAPP.GE_APLICACAO.GE_MENUAPLICACAOs
               select menu;
    }
```

I read a lot about it, and about subqueries, but I really can´t understand why it´s OK in some machines and not OK and another. Did I missed some fix in the installation?

Thanks.

Comment: Is it possible that some machines have .NET Framework 4 while the other .NET Framework 4.5?

Comment: Thanks Pawel, the problem has been resolved after we installed .NET 4.5. How can I mark the comment as the answer?

Comment: I posted the comment as the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it possible that some machines have .NET Framework 4 while the other .NET Framework 4.5?